# Win32_DiskDrive Serial Number in VMWare

Tags: wmi, vmware, hard-drive

I've a VMWare Workstation 10.0 Virtual Machine with 1 hard disk configured.

When I use wbemtest to perform the following query in WMI:

SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive

I see the serial number is null.

How can I get VMWare to populate this field? I can't find anywhere in the UI, I've tried adding:

ddb.serialNumber = "dfaklsjdfkajlsd"

to the .vmdk file but this seems to have done nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you able to find solution?

Comment: @jtro see my answer below, change the virtual disk type to IDE and then it'll have a serial number automatically.

Comment: I have change to IDE but still serial number configuration not coming. I have also checked serial number in cmd but getting 000…1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

In VMWare Workstation if your virtual hard disk type is SCSI then I can find no way of having a serial number. However, create a virtual disk with a type of IDE and it'll have a serial number by default.